# Why does regex doesn't match

Tags: java, regex

I have wrote the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "'7858','1194','FSP,FRB,FWF,FBVS,FRRC','15'\n"
                + "'7859','1194','FIRM','21'";
        String pattern = "^'*','*','*','*'$";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));               
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }

    }
```

it returns `NO MATCH` always.

expected result - 2 rows

What do I wrong ?

Comment: Please include the input and your expected output.

Comment: Did you mean `.*`?

Comment: `m.group(1)` will probably fail as well since your expression doesn't contain any capturing group. `m.group(0)` will always return the entire match so it doesn't do what you probably think it does (read the JavaDoc for more information).

Comment: Also not that `^...$` will make the expression match the _entire_ string and since yours seems to contain 2 lines (the variable name `line` is misleading here) it probably won't work as expected when fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code :

- A single "star" (*) in matches 0-N times the character it follows - in your code, `'*'` means "match 0-N times a single quote, followed by another single quote"
- Also, the "star" qualifier is "greedy" by default, meaning it will eat as many matching chars as possible, including the ending quote in your groups. In your case, you may want to set it in "reluctant" mode (by appending a `?` to it : `*?`), so that it matches only the text inside the single quotes.
- The lines must be matched one by one, so the initial multi-line must be split on the line-separator character (`\n`). Unless you use the multi-line match option, but I think this is not what you want here.
- Matching groups start at 1, not 0, so groups would be numbered 1 to 4 in your case.

Here is your code, corrected as explained above :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line = "'7858','1194','FSP,FRB,FWF,FBVS,FRRC','15'\n" +
            "'7859','1194','FIRM','21'";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)','(.*?)','(.*?)','(.*?)'");

    String[] lines = line.split("\n");
    for (String l : lines) {

        System.out.println("Line : " + l);

        Matcher m = r.matcher(l);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(4));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the result :

```
Line : '7858','1194','FSP,FRB,FWF,FBVS,FRRC','15'
Found value: 7858
Found value: 1194
Found value: FSP,FRB,FWF,FBVS,FRRC
Found value: 15
Line : '7859','1194','FIRM','21'
Found value: 7859
Found value: 1194
Found value: FIRM
Found value: 21
```

Answer (score 0):

`"^'*','*','*','*'$"` does not match anything because `'*` searches for as many `'`s as possible. It does not match what you want. 
Also, the ^ and $ won't work.

I think that this regex is what you need:

```
'[0-9A-Z,]*','[0-9A-Z,]*','[0-9A-Z,]*','[0-9A-Z,]*'
```

Here I have added the character class `[0-9A-Z,]` to match numbers, letters and `,`s. I think that this will give you what you need.

Comment: Instead of `[0-9A-Z,]*` you could use `[^']*` to match anything except a single quote - or use a reluctant quantifier e.g. `.*?`.

Comment: @Thomas Yes you are right, but OP's data contains only this, so I added only that character class.

Comment: In that case you'd need to use `[0-9]` for all but the 3rd "group" ;)

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I think you are right! I can see that the first group looks like some serial numbers, the second is some constant, the third is .. a set of F words (LOL).. . But still, I think OP can modify that himself! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this expression:

```
(?<=^|[\r\n]+)'([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)'(?=[\r\n]+|$)
```

Breakdown:

- `(?<=^|[\r\n]+)` is a positive look-behind checking for either the start of the input or a sequence of linebreak characters
- `'([^']*)'` matches and captures one of your groups. You could use `'(.*?)'` (i.e. a reluctant qualifier) instead but the former version is safer since it won't match if your input lines contain more than 4 groups
- `(?=[\r\n]+|$)` is a positive look-ahead checking your groups are followed by either a sequence of linebreak characters of the end of the input sequence

I also made the following assumptions about your code:

- Your input contains multiple lines which you can't or don't want to split (otherwise `String[] lines = input.split("[\\r\\n]+")` would be better).
- A matching line always consists of 4 groups which you want to access using `group(1)` etc.
- Your groups can contain any character except a single quote. If a group is only allowed to contain certain characters (e.g. digits), it would be safer to reflect that in the expression (e.g. `'[0-9]+'`)